# Why does 0.0 == False return True in Python?

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I would like to know why `0.0== False` returns `True` in Python. I know `0==False` returns `True` because `Bool` is a subclass of `int` so essentially you are comparing the same data type but is the same true for float?

Comment: The duplicates are not exactly the same question, but what you are trying is similar to `int(0) == float(0)`, which is also `True`.

Comment: print(bool(float(0.00))) comes out false which means float of 0.00 is false which is why 0.0==False returns True.

Comment: @RajVerma: No, the float is not interpreted as a boolean. If it was, `2.0 == True` would be true.

Comment: bool(0) is False which is True and bool(0.0) is also false which is correct. Hence when you say 0.00==False or 0==False it comes True. its the condition. Checked n tested. I never said float is treated as bool.

Comment: @RajVerma: `bool(2.0)` is `True`, but `2.0 == True` is false.

Comment: right, but that's not the point.

Comment: @RajVerma I think your comment is a bit misleading, just because some combination of type conversions can make two values equal, doesn't mean that `==`ing them will or should resolve `True`.

Comment: Sure, I get it!